# Google App Script Spreadsheet Form error

Tags: forms, triggers, google-apps-script

**Separate issue raised with Google by st...@ditoweb.com [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=2391) (issue 2391)**

We have an iframe-based spreadsheet form on a website (http://www.monarch-equestrian.co.uk/brochurerequest.html) which is set to generate emails with attached PDF's to respondents.

Over the past few days, this has been generating an error notification - "You do not have permission to call getActiveSpreadsheet". The script, triggered on submission, has been working perfectly - however the spreadsheet had grown to 1387 rows so we archived it and deleted most of the records in the original (in case we had reached the limit allowed and so we wouldn't have to create a new spreadsheet etc).

The question is, even though the spreadsheet is presumably now within data limits and all the settings are unchanged, why are we still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reported issue noted in the question, this was fixed Feb 25, 2013.